# horizontal gradient doesn't work on dynamic width content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, gradient

I am trying to implement gradient for button or view depending on requirement. But whenever I try to do so for button/view who's width is dynamic (for horizontal gradient) it only loads half the same.

```
func applyGradient(withColours colours: [UIColor], gradientOrientation orientation: GradientOrientation) {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = orientation.startPoint
    gradient.endPoint = orientation.endPoint
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

GradientOrientation is obtained by following code.

```
enum GradientOrientation {
case topRightBottomLeft
case topLeftBottomRight
case horizontal
case vertical

var startPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.startPoint
}

var endPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.endPoint
}

var points: GradientPoints {
    switch self {
    case .topRightBottomLeft:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0), CGPoint.init(x: 1.0, y: 0.0))
    case .topLeftBottomRight:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1))
    case .horizontal:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), CGPoint.init(x: 1.0, y: 0.5))
    case .vertical:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
    }
}
}
```

But if the width is 150 it loads up perfectly for both view/button. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the frame of your button is not the same when you apply the gradient as it is later on. You can try printing bounds in `applyGradient` to check.

You should add a bit more logic anyway; since this looks like a subclass of a view it would be great to store the layer. Currently what do you expect will happen if `applyGradient` is called twice? You will most likely have 2 gradients.

So you would add:

```
private var currentGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?
func applyGradient(withColours colours: [UIColor], gradientOrientation orientation: GradientOrientation) {
    currentGradientLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    currentGradientLayer = nil

    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
         let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
         gradient.frame = self.bounds
         gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
         gradient.startPoint = orientation.startPoint
         gradient.endPoint = orientation.endPoint
    }()

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)    
    currentGradientLayer = gradient
}
```

Now since that is done you should try to override 2 more methods to fix the frames:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    refreshGradientLayer()
}
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        refreshGradientLayer()
    }
}
private func refreshGradientLayer() {
    currentGradientLayer?.frame = bounds
}
```

This should refresh the gradient in any case; `layoutSubviews` will be called when your view is layout with constraints and `frame` when it is done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

All sublayers in UIView.layer do not change their size automatically when changing the super layer. Override the method of `UIView.layoutSubviews()` and update bounds CAGradientLayer from UIView.layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<gradientlayer>.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Call this method after you done calculating the width of the dynamic component.